# JS graph not showing up in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a page that I'm building to monitor varnish for our servers.  In it I have some js to create a pie graph.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="wz_jsgraphics.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pie.js"></script>
<div id="space" style="overflow: auto; position:relative;top:0;height:350px;width:380px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var s = new pie();
  s.add("Free",60);
  s.add("Used",40);
  s.render("space", "Pie Graph")    
</script>
```

It displays correctly on that page.  I have another page with an `<iframe>` tag to pull several pages together.  Everything shows up on this second page as expected except for the graph.  I've looked at it in Chrome, IE, and FireFox.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: No errors displayed in your browser's console perhaps?

Comment: Thanks, I did have an error about being sandboxed. I added `sandbox="allow-scripts"` to my `<iframe>` and that seemed to fix it.  Now I have a bunch of syntax errors that are not present in the original page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS (Cross Origin Request Sharing) established correctly? depending on where those "other pages" are pulling from, it may be a violation of the sandbox security model

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to get back to you.  The "other pages" are in sub directories under my index page that have the iframes, so I don't believe that would be too much of an issue.